# Style differs from chrome to IE. Centering

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am attempting to center a page. The page appears centered in chrome and FF. IE shoves everything to the left. Where I get confused is I'm using 1 style sheet for multiple pages and several of those pages are correct across all browsers. Best guess is something I have styled on the page is generating the incorrect formatting.

The only solution that works is if I apply a `text align: center` but this is not feasible for their are several other text styles already though out the body.

I have tried 
 changing the margin from 
          `margin: 0` 
to 
        `margin: 10px auto 0;` 
 and
 `.container{width:auto;}` to a fixed width by changing it to    `.container{width:900px;}`

I attached a jsfiddle here though im not sure it will help identify the problem as it looks centered. http://jsfiddle.net/thetylercox/p6ENV/

The current problem is here. 
http://www.redwirelogic.com/index.html 
 When i find the problem ill update the fiddle to show the problem and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the issue :

```
#wrapper { width:100%; overflow:hidden; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }

/* Wrapper Sub Elements */
.w-main { width:1004px; margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden; }
```

Basically you are creating a "wrapper" that is the same width as the current window. Then you create a child element which has a set width `1004px` with auto left / right margins.

The reason this bumps to the left most edge of the window is because your `#wrapper` element is text-aligning left.

What you should do is something simple like :

```
#wrapper { width:100%; overflow:hidden; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; 
        text-align:center; } // <-- that 

/* Wrapper Sub Elements */
.w-main { width:1004px; margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden; 
         text-align:left;} // <----and this
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response didn't notice this! Thanks so much trying the fix now and will respond with details.

Comment: flawless fix! on to the next problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are in quirks mode. Change your doctype to something like

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

or

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

and no need to align center. This is going to solve lot of your other problems in IE too.